# Android Programming - How to display .swf

Tags: java, android, flash

Is it possible to run a .swf on Android running Froyo 2.2? If so, how do I do it? I am basically trying to do a cool animation and it is done in Flash but I have no idea how to show that animation on the Android.

Answer (score 2):

one way of doing this is creating an html page in wich you play the swf, then opening the html in a webview component

Comment: Yes, but you need an internet connexion. I would like to play a swf file in a part of my application.. Thank a lot for any help